# Why did my Gchat easter egg animations stop working?

Tags: gmail, google-talk

I frequently use the chat popup in Gmail to talk with my husband while we are working. Today I typed "Woot" to something he said, and the little happy animation guy didn't show up (for either of us). We tried some other commands that we remembered (such as /ponystream) and still did not trigger any animations.

Did Google turn that feature off, or is there a setting that one of us changed (perhaps by accident)?

I am using Firefox 38.0.1. I have not downloaded any additional software, and am accessing chat from the gmail page (it's docked into my browser, I'm not sure if that is old chat, hangouts or what).

Comment: Please add more details like if you are using the old chat or Hangouts and the browser name and version. By the way I just tried /ponystream and it works fine in the Hangouts extension for Chrome.

Comment: @Rubén added more details, but I don't know how to tell if I'm using the old chat or Hangouts?

Comment: Thanks. I just replaced my previous answer by a new one. By the way, I think that you are using Hangouts.

Comment: For me the easter eggs with a / only work.

Answer (score 1):

Try with `Woot!!` (with two exclamation symbols) instead of `Woot` (without exclamation symbol).

It's worth to say that not all Google Hangouts easter eggs work in Gmail. There are some them that only work in the Hangouts Extension or Hangouts Desktop Application for Chrome.

**References**
[Hangouts Easter Eggs - Moritz Tolxdorrff (Googler)](https://plus.google.com/+MoritzTolxdorff/posts/MFHshpinpeJ)

Comment: Nope still doesn't work (I've tried multiple commands, and none of them seem to be working). Also I'm currently on a different machine than earlier, and still don't have the easter eggs.

Comment: I did several tests. Not always the animation it's shown, so keep trying. Also consider to send feedback to the Hangouts team. To do this, click the dropdown menu next to your name, then Feedback and fill up and send your feedback.